# Play: configure logging using run-main

Tags: logging, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I have a Play application (Play 2.2.3) where I configured my logging in a custom `conf/application-logger.xml` file (working fine during the execution of the application).

In addition I also need sometimes to run a script outside of the application, then I am using the command `run-main`. My problem is that my custom logging configuration is not taken when I am using run-main.

Do you know how can I force the using of my conf file or define another logging configuration file?

Thanks a lot.

**Edit**
I also tried to specify the conf file in the play command, [as described here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SettingsLogger#Changing-the-logback-configuration-file), without success:
`play "run-main my.package.MyClass -Dlogger.resource=conf/application-logger.xml"`
.

Answer (score 0):

`sbt` has a setting which lets you override java command line options.  Either temporarily, from the sbt console:

```
set javaOptions in Runtime += "-Dlogger.file=conf/application-logger.xml"
```

Or persistently, in your Build.scala

```
javaOptions in Runtime +=  "-Dlogger.file=conf/application-logger.xml",
```

Comment: Here is what I obtain:

    [info] Defining runtime:javaOptions  
    [info] The new value will be used by test:run::runner, test:testGrouping   
    [info] Reapplying settings...

But the new configuration file is still not loaded (neither with run nor run-main command).

When I use only `run` command I can indeed load a custom file:  
`run -Dlogger.file=conf/custom-logger.xml`  

But it is **not** loaded with the `run-main` command:  
`run-main my.package.MyClass -Dlogger.file=conf/custom-logger.xml`